# Binomial Distribution Problem Involving Excel

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

Here's the question: 7% of the American population has O-negative blood. if 10 people randomly donate blood, what is the probability that at least 1 of them has O-negative blood? (Round to 3 decimal places)

Here's the excel formula I used to solve it:

=BINOM.DIST(1,10,0.07,FALSE)

I got 0.387420489 as my answer, but it's incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain how the arguments work in Excel? In MATLAB I used binocdf(1,10,0.07,'upper') and I get about 0.152.

Comment: X, trials, probability, cumulative.

Comment: So you would actually want 1-BINOMDIST(0,10,0.07,FALSE) (or TRUE, they are the same in this case) because of the "at least" in the problem. If I understand the arguments correctly, you computed the probability of getting exactly $1$, not at least $1$.

Comment: Subtracting from 1 or saying TRUE still gives me an incorrect answer. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: What is supposedly the correct answer? (Perhaps your solution manual has some error.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is equivalent to not having all ten not O-negative, i.e.  $1-(1-0.07)^{10} \approx 0.516$.  Any of the following Excel formulae will give this:

```
=1-(1-0.07)^10

=1-BINOM.DIST(0,10,0.07,TRUE)

=1-BINOM.DIST(0,10,0.07,FALSE)

=1-BINOM.DIST(10,10,0.93,FALSE)

=BINOM.DIST(9,10,0.93,TRUE)
```